# Can I use a ternary operator to set a generic method parameter?

Tags: c#, generics, ternary-operator

I've got a very useful utility method that accepts any object type and serializes it as an XML object.  The method parameter is defined as a generic like so

```
public static string Serialize<T>(T value)
```

I usually send a web server request or response to this method before logging it and that has worked fine in all cases for me so far.  Now however I have a block of code in which I could be using one of two request objects so I'd like to call the Serialize method like so

```
Utility.Serialize((addressRequest != null)?addressRequest:billingSiteIDHouseNumberRequest)
```

but I keep getting an error message stating that these types are not compatible.

I also think the ?? operator should work but alas it also give me an error.

Thanks for any explanation.

Comment: whats the type of both objects? it should be same to make ternary operator work

Comment: Or convertible from the 2nd operand to the 3rd, or vice versa.

Comment: Assuming these are 2 different object types but derive from the same class, you *might* be able to cast both to the parent type to get it to work. However, it's probably more clear/readable to just expand this to an `if`/`else`.

Comment: good point @JonSkeet

Comment: The object types are unrelated and are not convertable from one to the other.  There is no common parent class either.  Dave's answer below is what I should have coded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have different un-related types, you'll need to add the serialization bit into the ternary logic:

```
var result = addressRequest != null
    ? Utility.Serialize(addressRequest)
    : Utility.Serialize(billingSiteIDHouseNumberRequest);
```

Comment: Depending on exactly what `Serialize` does this might be needed even if the types are related, but not the same.

Comment: Dave, this is how I should have coded it to begin with, thanks for the timely response, and yes the types are unrelated.